# react-query: how to get the data from useQuery in onSuccess callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am learning `react-query` and I meet some problems. I want to use the `data` I get from fetching data by `useQuery`, but I get `data` as `undefined`. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { fetchData } from "./providesData";
const Home = () => {
  const {data} = useQuery("fetchData", fetchData, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log("Get data!");
      console.log(data); // undefined
    }
  });

  return <div></div>;
};

export default Home;
```

But I see in `react-query devtools` that the fetch is succeeded and the `data` is here. So I think I do not access the `data` in my `onSuccess` callback properly. So how can we get access to the `data` in the callback? I tried:

```
const query = useQuery("fetchData", fetchData, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log("Get data!");
      console.log(query.data); // undefined
    }
  });
```

but still no luck.

I read the [documentation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) and found this:

> onSuccess: (data: TData) => void

So I tried this in my code:

```
const {data} = useQuery("fetchData", fetchData, {
    onSuccess: (data: TData) => {
      console.log("Get data!");
      console.log(data); // success
    }
  });
```

This time it works. But I do not understand why... And the code editor also warned me:

```
Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)
```

Can anyone show me the right way to do it? Thank you so much!

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dirac-3us1b?file=/src/components/Home.js).

Comment: regarding your error: `:TData` is Typescript syntax. Leave it out if you are using JavaScript

Comment: @TkDodo Yeah, I am only using JavaScript. But weirdly it works.

Comment: if you are fetching data with a post request, it probably means you want to use `useMutation` instead of `useQuery`. `useMutation` will have the data as a parameter of the config callback `onSuccess`, while `useQuery` has data only if you are making a get request.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `onSuccess` callback function is called only when the `data` has been retrieved from the query. Carefully notice that this `data` is not the one that you're de-structuring from the `useQuery` return object, but the one that has been passed to the callback on successful retrieval of data from your API. Since, it is a callback function, you don't need to check for waiting/loading cases, as it will eventually be called if your request succeeds.

In your case, the first `data` variable will return `undefined` as soon as the `Home` component mounts, because the `useQuery` call
is an **asynchronous** call which means that data returned from the `useQuery` call **will need to be resolved from a `Promise`**. Thus, it will not be directly available as soon as the `Home` component mounts, but only after the query resolved successfully. Also, *react-query* `useQuery` hook calls the `onSuccess(data)` callback with the data received before the actual `data` object(the one returned by the `useQuery` hook) is set and returned from the hook.

Since `useQuery` is an asynchronous call (internally), it also provides `request in-flight` flags like `isLoading`, `isFetching`, etc. which you can use to null-check for data, errors, or any other purpose suitable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought `onSuccess` would be called after the `Promise` was resolved. So if I want to do something after the `Promise` is resolved, I should do `if(isSuccess) console.log(data)`.

Comment: Hi, can i return jsx element onSuccess ?

Answer (score 18):

I just did this:

```js
useQuery("fetchData", fetchData, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log("Get data!");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: As simple it could be. Thanks!

Comment: This looks deprecated

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/reference/useQuery